# The graph API is returning an unknown error when I comment on a post despite the fact that the comment is posted correctly

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to comment on a post via the Graph API:

```
FB.api(

    "/604597322_10152198339802323/comments",
    "POST",
    { 

        "access_token" : XXX,
        "message" : "comment..."
    },
    function ( response ) {

        ...
    }
);
```

The access token is fine, I can do other things such as post to my wall and like posts. The error I get is the singularly unhelpful "An unknown error has occurred."

The comment IS succesfully posted, which makes this doubly vexing, it's just that the graph API does not report it as such.

Just to confirm, if I type the following into my browser address bar with a valid access token...

https://graph.facebook.com/604597322_10152198339802323/comments?method=post&message=test&access_token=XXX

...I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 2
   }
}
```

However the comment has been successfully posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like bug in graph API. I am facing the same issue.
Have a look.
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/218862188300393/

I have also create a bug in fb bug tracker.

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/570569026365902/

Facebook support and development is very slow in solving bugs. Some bugs are assigned but still not solved yet. For them it seems not important but for us it makes huge impact... :(

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/356391864496461/

Hope this will give you some relief. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me and my apologies for taking so long to reply.

You're right, and I found out the same thing! I also have a bug created with them and yes, like you, they're slow in getting back to me!

I hope you found a workaround. I needed the post identifier in order to get the details of the comment, in particular the creation time, to update the user interface. In the end I looked for a comment with the same message, rather than identifier, which works well enough.

Thanks again for the reply.

:O)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this is a bug in Facebook's graph API. Comments are still welcome if you have found workarounds and so forth.